# Unable to iterate random values in subsequent lines in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, gmic

There are probably many more straightforward ways of achieving my aim here, but as a Python newbie, I'd appreciate it if we could just concentrate on the code I'm using.
I'm attempting to write out a list of commands for a graphics program (G'MIC) and output those to a command prompt (although not directly) using Python 3.6.4 (OS: Windows 10 Pro), I need to write many lines of code but each line has to have different sets of numbers (integers and floats).. for example in the code I'm attempting to use right now the syntax is like this:

```
gmic v -99 input_.png fx_pastell 
0.5,1,0,10,40,633,11,95,1,1,0.291651967558584,0,0,8,150,1,81,1,0,0,0 -o 
out_001.png
```

^  all the variables denote parameters within the particular script (in this case Pastell effect).

The code I wrote relies on the Random module to get certain numbers within a range for each parameter that I want to change.
My stumbling block is to get the script to output DIFFERENT random numbers each time it prints a line. Here is my code (it's awful, I know..):

```
import random

a = random.randint (3,13)
b = random.randint (1,68)
c = random.randint (1,682)
d = random.randint (2,12)
e = random.randint (1,109)
g = random.randint (1,8)
h = random.uniform (0, 1)
k = random.randint (1,11)
l = random.randint (1,201)
n = random.randint (1,300)
o = random.randint (1,4)

dataFile = open("gmic1.txt", "w")
for line in range(120):
    dataFile.write("gmic v -99 input_.png fx_pastell 0.5,1,0" + "," + str(a) 
+ "," + str(b) + "," + str(c) + "," +str(d) + "," + str(e) + ",1," + str(g) 
+ "," + str(h) + ",0,0," + str(k) + "," + str(l) + ",1,"  + str(n) + "," + 
str(o) +"," + "0,0,0 -o out_%04d.png \n" % line)

dataFile.close()
```

The output is like this:

```
gmic v -99 input_.png fx_pastell 
0.5,1,0,12,2,521,12,85,1,7,0.04003331068764937,0,0,8,17,1,297,2,0,0,0 -o 
out_0000.png 
gmic v -99 input_.png fx_pastell 
0.5,1,0,12,2,521,12,85,1,7,0.04003331068764937,0,0,8,17,1,297,2,0,0,0 -o 
out_0001.png 

.. etc...
```

no errors as such, but not outputting a different set of numbers each time as I'd hoped.

The first input image name variable I can change with Notepad++'s Column Editor, so that takes care of that, I only need to know how to make each line of code differ.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that you can use the G'MIC Python binding for this now: https://github.com/myselfhimself/gmic-py

Comment: @myselfhimself Thanks, how would one code the example Roomm provided below for example?

Comment: The comment is not directly gmic related. The idea is just to `pip install gmic` then `import gmic` then prepare the command string any way you want, then `gmic.run(the command string)`. See https://gmic-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html . Note that for now the gmic python module this will only install for Linux or MacOS sorry, not Windows. In the case of the example provided by Roomm, if the command is usefully stored in a .txt file for some reason, then one should get the file's contents into a string first, to pass to gmic.run. You might try running gmic.run("yourfile.gmic").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call rand function on every iteration

```
from random import randint, uniform

dataFile = open("gmic1.txt", "w")
for line in range(120):
    dataFile.write("gmic v -99 input_.png fx_pastell 0.5,1,0"
                   + "," + str(randint(3, 13))
                   + "," + str(randint(1, 68))
                   + "," + str(randint(1, 682))
                   + "," + str(randint(2, 12))
                   + "," + str(randint(1, 109))
                   + ",1," + str(randint(1, 8))
                   + "," + str(uniform(0, 1))
                   + ",0,0," + str(randint(1, 11))
                   + "," + str(randint(1, 201))
                   + ",1," + str(randint(1, 300))
                   + "," + str(randint(1, 4))
                   + "," + "0,0,0 -o out_%04d.png \n" % line)
dataFile.close()
```